# Can the public key be extracted from the message encrypted with it?

Tags: encryption, pgp

If I encrypt messages with Public Key, and give the recepient Private Key to decrypt it, can the recepient somehow extract the Public Key from the messages?

I.e. is it OK to keep "Public Key" in secret, to encrypt messages, and give the "Private Key" to the third parties so they could decrypt messages, but not create their own with the same Public Key?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point : You never give the Private Key.

You give the Public Key so that people may send you encrypted messages
that only you can decrypt with your Private Key.

If you want to send an encrypted message, your correspondent should
create his own Private Key and give you his Public Key to use for
encrypting your messages.

Comment: OK, but this is not the answer for question "Can the public key be extracted from the message encrypted with it?"

Comment: No, it cannot. But in any case the public key is just that, public, and available for everyone.